# How to use gulp + browserify with multi-stage config files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a browserify app that I need to deploy to multiple stages: development, staging, production, and usually I would have separate config files, such as `config/development.json`, etc. but I can't seem to find any information about how to do this. I would think this would be a common problem.

Comment: Please, be more specific. You can include your config file in your browserify task with [require](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#brequirefile-opts). `browserify({...}).require('config/development.json', {expose: 'config'}).bundle()...`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I wish this was a bit more obvious.